# Cant find out how to wait for ajax call to complete before .each is continuing

Tags: javascript, ajax, each

My name is Dan and i am not that experienced with Javascript, but i have come up with some code where the desired functionality is that for $.each div.extractedGroup send its .html() through $.ajax and wait for the response before the $.each continues with next group.

I am probably overcomplicating this, but how can i alter my code to do this?

What i have tried is to set up a variable that are true when the ajax call is beforeSend, and and false upon success, an setTimeout function in the success event handler, and i have been trying to wrap the $.ajax call with an setTimeout function but with no success.
I think i am overcomplication this, but i cant seem to get my head around this.

**The javascript:**

```
$('#processGroup').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('.extractedGroup').each(function(index, el) {
    data = $(this).html();
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'wait.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            urlstoparse: data
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('sending: ' + data);
            //next in $.each should wait until success before next group is processed
        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            //next in $.each can now be processed
        }
    })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
});
```

});

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="responseResult" style="">
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/504262489497532154/,www.pinterest.com/pin/355080751843289362/,www.pinterest.com/pin/294704369339289320/,www.pinterest.com/pin/300685712590894312/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/555068722796876871/,www.pinterest.com/pin/69805862945258757/,www.pinterest.com/pin/94575660900159173/,www.pinterest.com/pin/521221356846916476/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/197173289911047820/,www.pinterest.com/pin/413486809511385544/,www.pinterest.com/pin/355080751843289327/,www.pinterest.com/pin/53691420527287022/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/135882113732404986/,www.pinterest.com/pin/464222674063278838/,www.pinterest.com/pin/339318153145966062/,www.pinterest.com/pin/31103053648675435/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/414542340674052776/,www.pinterest.com/pin/65583738298561215/,www.pinterest.com/pin/497718196292156699/,www.pinterest.com/pin/101753272800833432/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/421157002626993183/,www.pinterest.com/pin/43628690112051613/,www.pinterest.com/pin/414542340674052770/,www.pinterest.com/pin/220957925438000313/,</div>
<div class="extractedGroup">www.pinterest.com/pin/462322717970755136/,</div>
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to construct an object with your data to make one POST in lieu of looping over nodes and making many network requests. I'm not familiar with your endpoint, but it's typically considered bad practice to make a bunch of network requests separately.

Comment: You can't pause and wait in javascript, so you can't use `.each()` the way you are if you want each ajax call to finish before the next one.  Instead, you launch the next ajax call from the success handler of the previous one and keep track of where you are in the iteration with your own variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! jfriend00, you had my solution, i had to think in another way, i came up with making a function and keep track of where i am in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jfriend00 i learned that there is no pause and wait in javascript, making me rewrite my code like this:

```
var groups = $('.extractedGroup');
var i = 0;
getData(i, groups);

function getData(i, groups) {
    count = groups.length;
    if (i < count) {
    request = $.ajax({
        url: 'wait.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            urlstoparse: groups.eq(i).html()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('sending: ' + groups.eq(i).html());

        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            i = i + 1;
            getData(i, groups);
        }
    })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
}
}
```